# Form Library InfoPath Document Template - Is there a way to digitally sign the form, plus any documents attached to the form?

Tags: infopath, attachments, document-template, form-library, digital-signature

I have a form library with a template created through InfoPath.

The template allows users to attach additional documents to it.

For audit purposes, each "page" (form + each attachment) needs to have a signature in the bottom right hand corner.

It's pretty easy to add a signature field to the form itself, but is there any way, through SharePoint, to add signatures to the attachments, as well?

Answer (score 0):

Not without custom coding. You would have to create custom logic that while main form is signed it would sign the other documents as well (you can do that with administrator approved IP form, they can have custom C# code behind). But beware of holding attachments in IP form. It will brake the form when you have them too many or they are too big. In SP2013 they brake around 15-20 MB I believe.